# Capturing elements inside a div class

Tags: java, arrays, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Below is the same code

```
<section id=“zone_body” class =“zone zone_body>

<div class =“row”>…<div>

<div data-o_id="4915279" data-renderertype="imagesonly" class="module module-carousel module-carousel--imagesonly col col--1-1" id="module-2319657">

::after

</div>

<div class =“row”>…<div>

<div class =“row”>…<div>

<div class =“row”>…<div>

<div class =“row”>…<div>

<div class =“row”>…<div>

<div class =“row”>…<div>

<div class =“row”>…<div>


</section>
```

I am testing a web page which I am trying to automate using selenium with Java. As per the html code above every page that I am testing has this standard 16 different types of data-renderertype and as per the code above the 8 different div class inside the body can have the same or a different data-renderertype all together, e.g above has "imagesonly" and can be in any random order. What I really want to achieve is to extract all the data-renderertype values from all the 8 (this is not a constant number as it can vary depending upon the page) different div class so it can be stored and used to compare it to a different version of the site. I hope this make sense, any help would be very much appreciated as I am overwhelmed right now and not sure where to start.

Comment: do there id starts with name module always i.e. id="module......"

Comment: Yes they are always id="module-xxxx" @AshishKamble

Comment: ok then use By.XPath("*//div[starts-with(@id,'module')]")

Comment: @Ajit Instead of providing a _tailor-made_ HTML, update the question with the text based actual relevant HTML for further analysis.

Answer (score 0):

you can make logic like this,

```
List<IWebElement> elements= driver.findElements(By.XPath("*//div[data-renderertype]"));
```

or

```
List<IWebElement> elements= driver.findElements(By.XPath("*[data-renderertype]"));
```

or

```
List<IWebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.XPath("*//div[starts-with(@id,'module')]"));
forEach(IWebElement ein elements){
    string str = e.getAttribute("data-renderertype");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<WebElement> allRows = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#zone_body > div.row"));

for( WebElement elem : allRows ){

   System.out.println("Value=== " + elem.getAttribute("data-renderertype"));
}
```

Comment: This is what I got 
Value=== null
Value=== null
Value=== null
Value=== null
Value=== null
Value=== null
Value=== null

Comment: Would you try the same code, just replace 'data-renderertype' with 'id' and share the result

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is :

1. Get item using `List<WebElement> divs = driver.findElements(By.xpath("#zone_body .row"))` (note that your XPath needs to be chosen carefully for the sake of your Selenium script stability and maintainability)
2. Stream over the list and use `WebElement.getAttribute("data-renderertype")` for each element, populating your new list or map or whatever data type you would want.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(by.xpath("//section[@id='zone_body']//div[@class='row']"));
for(int i=0;i<elements.size();i++) {
    System.out.println( elements.get(i).getAttribute("data-renderertype"));
}
```

This snippet gets all the `<div class='row'/>` elements under `<section id='zone_body' />` tag into elements list, iterating the list with a for loop to get the attribute data-renderertype's value.